# How to use jQuery events on non-DOM-related objects and their properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to use jQuery events on non-DOM-related objects.

This works fine:

```
var o = {

}

$(o).on('bump', function () {
  alert('ouch')
})

$(o).trigger('bump')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d35bf35y/

But instead I need to attach an event on a property... the following code does not work.

```
var o = {
    prop: 'test'
}

// Bind an event handler
$(o.prop).on('bump', function () {
  alert('ouch')
})

// Trigger an event
$(o.prop).trigger('bump')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d35bf35y/1/

In my real application that property will have an object.

I would like to know if is possible use jQuery in this way or an alternative solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "In my real application that property will have an object."

That part is rather important. This works:

```
var o = {
    prop: {}
}

// Bind an event handler
$(o.prop).on('bump', function () {
  alert('ouch')
})

// Trigger an event
$(o.prop).trigger('bump')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach one on the Object and everytime it fires, you run a function that does something with your properties. (check if they're the same, or else)

```
var o = {
  prop: 'test'
};

$(o).on('bump', function (e) {
  var props = e.delegateTarget;
  // do what you gotta do, like check if something has changed from before.
})

$(o).trigger('bump')
```

Or if your property is also an object, it should work.